# X.PagedList, manual Paging and a pre-existing webapi for data only advance 1 record at a time

Tags: asp.net-core, paging, pagedlist

Setting up a PagedList in .netcore against a webapi that already exists.

The webapi allows me to call data using a 2 parameters, a FROM and a TAKE.  I've implemented X.PagedList and it appears to work except for how it/I calculate the actual Page..

Using the code at [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList), I implemented the Manual Paging.  The issue is that when I click on a page number, my TAKE only takes 1 new record, as opposed to the NEXT 10.

On the first load, my api call looks like this

/api/v1/Institutions?from=0&take=10

The Page 2 call looks like

/api/v1/Institutions?from=1&take=10

Obviously the 1 should be 11 i think in this case

**PagedResults Class**

```
public class PagedResults<T> : List<T>
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public bool Empty { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public IActionResult PagedList(int? page)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = Title;
        ViewData["PageTitle"] = Title + " List";

        var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1;
        var pageSize = 10;

        //Perform API Call
        var response = GetList(pageIndex, pageSize);

        //Returns List<Institution>
        var Institutions = response.Data;

        //Returns 200, which is the total from the Headers
        string total = response.Headers.Where(x => x.Name == "total").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        var PagedList = new StaticPagedList<Institution>(Institutions, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, Convert.ToInt32(total));

        var model = new InstitutionViewModel
        {
            CurrentUser = CurrentUser //From BaseController
        };

        string view = string.Format("~/views/Portal/{0}/List.cshtml", Title);

        ViewData["PagedList"] = PagedList;

        return View(view, model);
    }
```

**GetList()**

```
#region Helpers

public static IRestResponse<List<Models.Institution>> GetList(int from, int take)
{
    //this create /api/v1/institutions?from=0&Take=10
    string ActionPath = string.Format("Institutions");

    var client = new RestClient(Connect.url);
    var request = new RestRequest(ActionPath, Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("from", from, ParameterType.QueryString);
    request.AddParameter("take", take, ParameterType.QueryString);

    var result = client.Execute<List<Models.Institution>>(request);

    return result;
}

#endregion
```

**My View**

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core; 
@using X.PagedList; 

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.PagedList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.id</td>
        <td>@item.name</td>
    </tr>
}

 @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.PagedList, page => Url.Action("PagedList", new { page }))
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.What is your `GetList` method?How did you get the CurrentUser? And how did you use `PagedResults`?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to add the GetList function.  Edited and added.  The currentuser comes from a base class and is unrelated.  The PagedList is used in a foreach to build the table and in the paging mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workaround like below:

1.View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Listing";
    var pagedList = (IPagedList)ViewBag.PageList;
}
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core; @*import this so we get our HTML Helper*@
@using X.PagedList; @*import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)*@
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Common
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Fluent
<ul>
    @foreach (var name in ViewBag.PageList)
    {
        <li>@name</li>
    }
</ul>
@Html.PagedListPager(pagedList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        ViewBag.PageList = GetPagedNames(page);
        return View();
    }

    protected IPagedList<string> GetPagedNames(int? page)
    {
        // return a 404 if user browses to before the first page
        if (page.HasValue && page < 1)
            return null;
        // retrieve list from database/wherever
        var listUnpaged = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ,"ddd","eee","fff","ggg","1","s","f","sd","dsfds"};
        // page the list
        const int pageSize = 10;
        var listPaged = listUnpaged.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, pageSize);
        // return a 404 if user browses to pages beyond last page. special case first page if no items exist
        if (listPaged.PageNumber != 1 && page.HasValue && page > listPaged.PageCount)
            return null;
        return listPaged;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this always just returns a single recordset of 10, therefore only 1 page

Comment: Hi @Tim Cadieux,did you test by using my code?And you think it only one page due to you see `public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)`?If so,I suggest that you could try it.I have rendered pagination  successfully.

Comment: I have but I'm not sure how it qould help me as I don't see it as a proper Paged List.  The reason for that is the way the code is written, it would grab all 5000 records on each call, the return a pagedList from that.  That seems highly inefficient and goes against what I'm tring to do.  I want to only return the necessary 10 records on each call, simply moving the cursor forward or backward based on the request.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @TimCadieux,Your thoughts make sense.And my code actually returns the necessary 10 records.You could set breakpoints and debug.You would find that evert time you choose the page,it only returns necessary 10 records in this line:`var listPaged = listUnpaged.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, pageSize);`